# How to reduce carousel height of Clearing Lightbox in Foundation 5?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Unfortunately, I was not able to find an already answered question that covers this topic. A related question has not been asked yet:

I am trying to reduce the height of the thumbnail carousel of the clearing lightbox in Foundation 5 in order to make more space for the displaying picture on the top. I am using CSS instead of SCSS in an extra CSS stylesheet to overwrite the CSS Foundation settings.

[image]

Zurb's related documentation on the Clearing Lightbox states the following SCSS variables (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html):

```
// We use these to make the image and carousel height and style
$clearing-active-img-height: 75%;
$clearing-carousel-height: 150px;
$clearing-carousel-thumb-width: 175px;
$clearing-carousel-thumb-active-border: 4px solid rgb(255,255,255);
```

Using normal CSS-code this should translate in the following to reduce the height to 100px:

```
.clearing-assembled .clearing-container .carousel {
height: 100px;}
```

Unfortunately this does not change the height of the carousel.

I would appreciate your help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the css like the following for it to work. You may need to tweak the numbers.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
   .clearing-assembled .clearing-container .visible-img {
       height: 92%;
   }

   .clearing-assembled .clearing-container .carousel > ul li {
       width: 50px;
   }

   .clearing-assembled .clearing-container .carousel {
       width: 50px;
   }

}
```

Comment: This works fine to reduce the height of the carousel. However, the displayed picture at the top (935 × 568 pixel) does not display fully at smaller resolutions. Is there a way to always enforce full display at all resolutions?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing what is happening. Is there somewhere I can see it?